# Simple SELECT * FROM 4 GB table LIMIT 1 takes 0.5 plus secs. What could be wrong?

Tags: mysql, configuration, database-administration, query-performance

A simple `SELECT * FROM [4 GB table] LIMIT 1` takes 0.5 plus seconds to execute. What could be wrong?

The whole DB contains 70 GB of data and 4 tables have 4~5 GB size; the rest are no greater than 1 GB. Twenty tables are Innodb and one is MyISAM. Server is running on m3.2xlarge instance.

UPDATE: 
I just noticed that not only in a 4GB table table this is happening but to all tables. In fact, I tried to query from the smallest table with one row and one column `SELECT * FROM smallest_table` the query time is *~0.4s*.  Could this be a configuration issue? I have made no changes on configuration lately.

Comment: Generally speaking adding hardware to try to fix slow queries is a waste of money. Good query performance comes from well-chosen indexes well used. Please read this and pay attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Then [edit] your question to give the information needed for us to help you.

Comment: http://thebuild.com/blog/2014/11/18/when-limit-attacks/

Comment: @DragandDrop that link is PostgreSQL not MySQL..

Comment: @O.Jones this table is contains only one index which is id and its PRIMARY. No need to put some index as the query suggests.

Comment: Well is a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1` any faster?

Comment: Using LIMIT 1 without ORDER BY is meaningless. Because there isn't a defualt returning order when returning records.

Comment: Also r4.xlarge would be much more suited as a database server than 
 an m3.2xlarge

Comment: @AshleyMedway , it doesn't get any better

Comment: @RaymondNijland, and you think that is the reason of the lag?

Comment: No i didnt say that.. use PROFILE to see what's causing the lag.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profile.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland the `SHOW PROFILE` gives a contrary report to the query the slowest which is _checking permissions = 0.000051._ This made more confused. Does the result give any hint?

Comment: Please run SHOW PROFILE ALL FOR QUERY [id]`` and post the results in your post.

Comment: @RaymondNijland https://imgur.com/a/ayBqh

Comment: @tatskie From that profile, it looks like it's take a total over less than 1 millisecond—at least for the execution time alone. So the 500 milliseconds (0.5 seconds) you reported must be coming from something else, like network transfer time or some code in your client.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- are there lots of `TEXT`/`BLOB` columns?  Is the query really as simple as you say -- no `ORDER BY`, etc?

Comment: @RickJames no  `TEXT` / `BLOB` just plain `VARCHAR`, `BIGINT`, and `DECIMAL`. 
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1` gives the same ~0.5 sec

Comment: btw, I just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong?  MyISAM.  Example:  In 3 different threads, suppose you have

```
SELECT ... FROM this_table ...; -- running more than 0.5 sec
INSERT INTO this_table ...;
SELECT * FROM this_table LIMIT 1;  -- this query
```

Q1 starts running, acquiring a read-lock on this_table.
Q2 starts, but wants an exclusive-lock on this_table, so it hangs.
Q3 starts, but is stuck behind the exclusive lock, so it hangs.

Finally, Q1 finishes, letting Q2 finish, which lets Q3 finish.

This is a drawback of MyISAM.

If I have guessed wrong, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and, if possible, `SHOW PROCESSLIST` *during* the 0.5s delay.

Comment: But the table is not MyISAM. How to `SHOW PROCESSLIST` during the 0.5s delay? by the time I fired `SHOW PROCESSLIST` the query should have been done.

Comment: Also provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I contend that that EXPLAIN did _not_ come from `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 1`.